# selenium ide verify integer is 2 digit

Tags: variables, selenium-ide

I've been trying to get pull a number from an HTML page, this number is a month and requires to have 2 integers. I frequently get 2 rather then 02. I'm looking for help in finding a way to verify that it is a 2 digit number and if not add a 0.

Variable name: ${ExpiryMonth}

Currently pulls value of 2 would like value of 02
If value is 12 would like it to verify and approve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I feel like this will be a valid solution however I'm just having a hard time getting it formatted to selenium ide. Thus far I have verifyEval|javascript{storedVars['ExpiryMonth'][regexp:[0-9][0-9]]}|${ExpiryMonth}

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a regular expression to verify against. For the case of looking for two digits you would use `regexp:[0-9][0-9]`

Now I am not yet used to using Selenium variables, so you might be looking for another syntax, but the following works to verify that the regular expression is working. The first `verifyEval` will pass and the second will fail:

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>store</td>
>   <td>02</td>
>   <td>twodigits</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>verifyEval</td>
>   <td>storedVars['twodigits']</td>
>   <td>regexp:[0-9][0-9]</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>store</td>
>   <td>2</td>
>   <td>onedigit</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>verifyEval</td>
>   <td>storedVars['onedigit']</td>
>   <td>regexp:[0-9][0-9]</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax is slightly wrong, a better way to match would be the following

```
verifyEval | twodigit | ^[0-9]{2}$
```

AND

```
verifyEval | onedigit | ^[0-9]$
```

Explanation: The `^` at the start signifies it MUST start with a digit 0-9. The `$` at the end signifies it must not have anything after it.

`regex:[0-9]` would pass any string containing one (or more) digit - such as `xsdkjabfijewqbrjewbrew324sakfdbsa`

And likewise `[0-9][0-9] or [0-9]{2}` would pass any string with 2 digits.